# Get time intervals where the process was on each stage on Jinja SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, intervals, gaps-and-islands

I need to get the intervals where a process was on each stage, and take into account when the process went back to a stage. For example:

| stage_name | from_day | to_day |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 2 |
| B | 2 | 3 |
| B | 3 | 4 |
| B | 4 | 5 |
| C | 5 | 6 |
| B | 6 | 7 |
| D | 7 |  |

the process is currently on stage D

I want to get a table like this

| stage_name | from_day | to_day |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 2 |
| B | 2 | 5 |
| C | 5 | 6 |
| B | 6 | 7 |
| D | 7 |  |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a [`gaps and islands`](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/databases/sql-server/t-sql-programming-sql-server/introduction-to-gaps-and-islands-analysis/) problem and you may use the following approaches to solve this.

#### Approach 1

```sql
SELECT
    stage_name,
    MIN(from_day) as from_day,
    MAX(to_day) as to_day
FROM (
    SELECT
        *,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY from_day) - ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION  BY stage_name ORDER BY from_day) as grp
        FROM
            my_table
    ) t1

GROUP BY stage_name,grp
ORDER BY from_day, stage_name;
```

| stage_name | from_day | to_day |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 2 |
| B | 2 | 5 |
| C | 5 | 6 |
| B | 6 | 7 |
| D | 7 |  |

[View working demo on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ApdPYBKYAWdUmUnN1oS6Z/1)

#### Approach 2

```
SELECT
    stage_name,
    MIN(from_day) as from_day,
    MAX(to_day) as to_day
FROM (
    SELECT
        *,
       SUM(same) OVER (PARTITION BY stage_name ORDER BY from_day) as grp
    FROM (
        SELECT
            *,
            CASE 
                WHEN from_day = LAG(to_day,1,from_day) OVER (PARTITION BY stage_name ORDER BY from_day) THEN 0
                ELSE 1
            END as same
        FROM
            my_table
    ) t1
) t2
GROUP BY stage_name,grp
ORDER BY from_day, stage_name;
```

| stage_name | from_day | to_day |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 2 |
| B | 2 | 5 |
| C | 5 | 6 |
| B | 6 | 7 |
| D | 7 |  |

---

[View working demo on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ApdPYBKYAWdUmUnN1oS6Z/1)

The example above uses `from_day = LAG(to_day,1,from_day) OVER (PARTITION BY stage_name ORDER BY from_day)` to determine if the current rows `from_day` is the same as the previous rows `to_day` within the same `stage_name` group/partition ordered by `from_day`. If it is the same 0 is assigned otherwise 1. The output of this subquery has been included below for your perusal:

```sql
SELECT
    *,
    CASE 
        WHEN from_day = LAG(to_day,1,from_day) OVER (PARTITION BY stage_name ORDER BY from_day) THEN 0
        ELSE 1
    END as same
FROM
    my_table
ORDER BY from_day, stage_name;
```

| stage_name | from_day | to_day | same |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 2 | 0 |
| B | 2 | 3 | 0 |
| B | 3 | 4 | 0 |
| B | 4 | 5 | 0 |
| C | 5 | 6 | 0 |
| B | 6 | 7 | 1 |
| D | 7 |  | 0 |

The window function `SUM(same) OVER (PARTITION BY stage_name ORDER BY from_day)` is then used to find the cumulative sum of these differences, thus creating groups:

```sql
    SELECT
        *,
        SUM(same) OVER (PARTITION BY stage_name ORDER BY from_day) as grp
    FROM (
            SELECT
                *,
                CASE 
                    WHEN from_day = LAG(to_day,1,from_day) OVER (PARTITION BY stage_name ORDER BY from_day) THEN 0
                    ELSE 1
                END as same
            FROM
                my_table
        ) t1
     ORDER BY from_day, stage_name;
```

| stage_name | from_day | to_day | same | grp |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 2 | 0 | 0 |
| B | 2 | 3 | 0 | 0 |
| B | 3 | 4 | 0 | 0 |
| B | 4 | 5 | 0 | 0 |
| C | 5 | 6 | 0 | 0 |
| B | 6 | 7 | 1 | 1 |
| D | 7 |  | 0 | 0 |

Finally by grouping by the `stage_name` and `grp` we can find the desired values in each group, in this case the earliest `from_day` using `MIN` and the latest `to_day` using `MAX`